# .NET core SDK cannot be located vscode unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-container

[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlYZh.png)

I am on windows 10 I tried reinstalling .net multiple times and re installed vscode i am really despreate for soloutions now

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with your .csproj. If you are on windows I cannot recommend enough for you to switch to Visual Studio. Everything is integrated, and trust me. Visual studio code will run into these types of problems every 5 minutes, where visual studio will not. If you are using unity I remember having to change “targetting packet” in the .csproj to 4.7.1 every time I loaded visual studio code. If you are not using unity, make sure you have run “dotnet new console” and “dotnet restore”.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project file and take a look what kind of .net version is used there. Then look for that version in microsoft .net download page